# ContentResolver differences between GB and ICS?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

My app implements a custom content provider, I have Android JUnit tests for it both for basic operations and more complex ones (using ContentProviderOperations).

my tests pass on a GB emulator, but failing (due to unexpected behavior) on a JB device and ICS emulator.

what are the differences between Android versions that can cause different behavior ?

Comment: What is it that is suddenly failing? I am not aware of differences, they exist for sure though

Comment: how are they failing.. please share junit logs...

Comment: I succeeded in making one test to pass by removing a duplicate ContentProviderOperation.newInsert.

I made an experiment and created a test that adds the same insert ContentProviderOperation twice, the table has 'on conflict ignore' statement. the second insert doesn't get a row id. I run the same test on a GB emulator and the second insert does get a row id.